# Why are there "relations" on databases instead of just using SQL's join?

Tags: database, database-design

I always see in database articles or tutorials or... just everywhere where they use databases, they use a thing called relations. It comes to my mind instantaneously those little boxes with lists of field names and one field connected to another field in another box with a line.

I'm not an expert on databases (as you can probably tell) but the little bit I've used, I never needed relations. They always seemed to be redundant as I can always use JOIN to achieved what it seemed to me they are made for. Are they redundant or is there anything you can do with relations that you cannot do with JOIN? Or am I just talking nonsense?

Comment: DB relations/tables represent relation(ship)s/associations. This is the "relation" in "relational model" & "relationship" in "entity-relationship model". So-called "relation(ship)s" between tables are FK constraints which are for integrity (& optimization) & are not needed to query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Relations are not just about joins for SQL queries. Relations provide many benefits:

- Data integrity
- Query convenience
- Third party tool integration benefits
- "Self-describing" data model to future DBAs/developers working with the database
- Etc

Data integrity:
Relations help to ensure that your "order records" can't exist without a "customer record" for example. Simply by defining a relationship between customer and order, the database will ensure that this cannot happen. This helps to make sure that your database doesn't become a big pile of junk data

Query convenience:
Relations can make it easier to do certain types of queries. Deleting a customer record can automatically have the customer's orders deleted at the same time, thanks to the relationship between customer and order

Third party tool integration benefits
Many third party tools (O/R tools come to mind) rely on relations in order to work properly

Really, the list could go on and on...you should use them, they're very beneficial. Even if you don't perceive the value today, if you're working on a database project that will continue to grow over a long period of time, it would be to your benefit to set relationships up from the beginning.

I think that they're not that critical for small projects/one-off data models...but for anything of substance, you're better off using them.

Comment: Another nicely put answer, although I disagree with the idea that relationships in a database are not critical for small projects and one-offs. Small projects and one-offs often end up being institutionalized, and used for beyond their intended purpose (especially in an enterprise or small/medium sized business environment). Then, we begin to wish someone had nromallized and established relationships from the start . . .

Comment: Good point. I've seen many motivated business (non-techie) persons create homegrown tools or processes that assist them with some aspect of their job. Sometimes the tools gain momentum, and then other business folks begin to use them. These types of tools are often built with Access, Excel, etc., and are usually disgusting banes of a software developer's existence. For better or worse though, I wouldn't dissuade a business person from doing these types of things using whatever approach they're comfortable with since the process encourages creativity and can spark larger company improvements

Comment: As with anything else that adds further description to the data, explicitly defining the relations can also can help the query optimizer.

Answer (score 5):

A RELATION is a subset of the cartesian product of a set of domains (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Relation.html). In everyday terms a relation (or more specifically a *relation variable*) is the data structure that most people refer to as a table (although tables in SQL do not necessarily qualify as relations).

Relations are the basis of the relational database model.

*Relationships* are something different. A relationship is a semantic "association among things".

I think you are actually asking about referential integrity constraints (foreign keys). A foreign key is a data integrity rule that ensures the database is consistent by preventing inconsistent data from being added to it. Don't confuse foreign keys with relations because they are very different things.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming when you are reading about relations it is probably referring to foreign keys. If that's true, relations and joins are not different solutions for the same problem. They are 2 tools that accomplish different things, and they are usually used together.

A join as it sound like you know is part of a select query that let you get rows from more then 1 table.

A relation is part of the database structure its self that defines a rule. For example if you had a city table and a country table, you should have a relation pointing each row in the city table to a row in the country table. This would ensure the integrity of the data and not allow a city row to point to a country row that doesn't exist.

Asking "Why use relations when you can use joins?" to me sounds like asking 'Why do variables have types when I could read them anyway?".

Answer (score 2):

The theory behind databases is based on something called **[Relational Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)**. Relation is not a database specific term, it is derived from Relational Algebra.

JOIN is kind of Relation, there can be different kind of relations. Refer to [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28database%29) to  know more about what a Relation exactly is.

Answer (score 1):

The relationships established in a RELATIONAL database are the very core of the relational database model. In a database, we model entities. We use relationships between entities to maintain data integrity, and ensure the records are organized properly. Relationships also create indexes between related tables.

If you are not using the relationships, and/or modelling your table structure based upon the relationships between discrete entities, then you are not harnessing the true power of your relational database. Yes, you can make queries work, and yes, you can get the Db to do some usefule work. But can you ensure that, say, every Employee record is properly RELATED to the proper company? Can you ensure that there is only one record for that company, and that all the emplotyees of that company are related to that record?

Without designing your database structure around entities and the relationships between them, you might as well use a spreadsheet, or one big, flat table. RELATIONSHIPS and NORMALIZATION form the basis of the modern relational database.

Comment: *Relations* and _not_ "relationships" are the defining feature of the relational database model. Relations have nothing to do with referential integrity rules.

Answer (score 1):

An SQL table is an approximation of a relational model relation. Tables/relations (bases, views & query results) represent relations/relationships/associations. These are boxes & diamonds on ER (Entity-Relationship) & pseudo-ER diagrams. Most lines on such diagrams correspond to FK (foreign key) constraints. They are frequently but wrongly called "relations" or "relationships" but they are not. They are facts. An SQL FK says that a table's subrows appear elsewhere where they are a PK (primary key) or UNIQUE. Equivalently, it says that an entity participating in a relation/relationship/association also participates once in another one. Table meanings are necessary & sufficient to query. Constraints--including PKs, UNIQUEs & FKs--are not needed to query. They are consequences of the table relation/relationship/association choices & what situations/states can arise. They are for integrity to be enforced by the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

When Ed Codd developed the relational model of data for use with large scale databases, he based his design on the mathematics of relational calculus and algebra.  The results of this kind of mathematics is predictable with mathematical precision,  and Ed Codd was able to forecast with near mathematical precision how relational databases would behave before the first one was ever built.

In mathematics, a relation is a mathematical abstraction.  It's a subset of the cartesian product of two or more domains, as another responder said.  If that's as clear as mud to you, maybe you're not a mathematician.

No matter.  A good computer scientist can understand SQL tables fairly easily,  and recognize and exploit  the power of an SQL JOIN.  This understanding will do in place of a mathematical understanding of relations for many purposes.  An SQL table materializes a mathematical relation, approximately.  If you are careful with table design,  you can turn "approximately" into "exactly".