# “Relation” versus “relationship” in RDBMS/SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms, database-schema

Coming from question [“Relation” versus “relationship”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15208/relation-versus-relationship/15218#15218)

What are definitions of "relation" vs. "relationship" in RDBMS (or database theory)?

Update:
I was somewhat perplexed by comment to my question:

> "relation is a synonym for table, and
>   thus has a very precise meaning in
>   terms of the schema stored in the
>   computer"

Update2:
Had I answered incorrectly that question , in terms of RDBMS, having written that relation is one-side direction singular connection-dependence-link,
i.e. from one table to another while relationship implies (not necessarily explicitly) more than one link connection in one direction (from one table to another)?

Comment: Good question, but too technical for SO.  Any good answer, which will be based on academic issues and definitions, will get voted down and argued by those with high rep and no academic background.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA, I started to doubt in your visionary abilities, b/c it was not downvoted but [I've got a 1000-day ban without any previous warnings in English.stackExhange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3085/vgv8)

Comment: You are a funny guy, and serious about your learning.  Do not take SO so seriously.  I get banned every time I point out misinformation, even though all I am doing is supporting the FAQ "Above all be honest ... correct misinformation".  The site cannot lift its low tech image.  Reputation is a result of pupularity, not technical accuracy.  I don't find you offensive at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there "relations" on databases instead of just using SQL's join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190314/why-are-there-relations-on-databases-instead-of-just-using-sqls-join)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A RELATION is a subset of the cartesian product of a set of domains (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Relation.html). In everyday terms a relation (or more specifically a relation variable) is the data structure that most people refer to as a table (although tables in SQL do not necessarily qualify as relations).

Relations are the basis of the relational database model.

Relationships are something different. A relationship is a semantic "association among things".

Comment: May I suggest, elaborate a bit more for the non-theoretical people in the audience.

Comment: "Relation" is also used in mathematics to mean "relationship" in the sense of "association"--as is "function". A high school textbook of mine was "Functions & Relations". The words can mean the association ("intension" or "meaning" ) or a particular representation of that--say, a set of tuples of an appropriate form ("extension"). Both senses apply to "relation" in the relational model.

Answer (score 6):

Relation is a mathematical term [referring to a concept from set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation). Basically, in RDBMS world, the "relational" aspect is that data is organized into tables which reflect the fact that each row (tuple) is related to all the others. They are all the same type of info.

But then, your have ER (Entity Relationship) which is a modeling methodology in which you identify objects and their relationships in the real world. Then each object is modelled as a table, and each relationship is modelled as a table that contains only foreign keys.

For instance, if you have 3 entities: Teacher, Student, Class; then you might also create a couple of tables to record these 2 relationships: TaughtBy and StudyingIn. The TaughtBy table would have a record with a Teacher ID and a Class ID to record that this class is taught by this teacher. And the StudyingIn table would have a Student ID and a Class ID to reflect that the student is taking this class.

That way, each student can be in many Classes, and each Teacher can be in many classes without needing to have a field which contains a list of class ids in any records. SQL cannot deal with field containing a list of things.

Answer (score 0):

A relation is a table with columns and rows.
and 
relationship is association between relations/tables
for example employee table has relation in branch its called relationship between employee table and branch table