# Need of relations on Entities inspite of HQL joins

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Just started to learn Hibernate and a basic question in mind came up why need of Mapping(relations) like @OneToOne .If that could be handled through various joins(inner outer).Searching on net gave me this 
[Why are there "relations" on databases instead of just using SQL's join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190314/why-are-there-relations-on-databases-instead-of-just-using-sqls-join).
 But an example would have done great help and also a scenario where relation is required and cannot be handled with joins.

Comment: According to me writing an HQL(basically writing a join ) give us the freedom to not enforce relations between two tables.So I guess adding relations before hand has an overhead.Inspite as when required we can use joins(simple HQL).

Comment: Relation mapping in hibernate or in any other orm framework exists so that you don't have to write that join query explicitly , but hibernate would create those for you once you try to fetch the entity .

Comment: I would suggest you to go through the concepts of paradigm mismatch between OOP and RDBMS first in order to understand the requirement and adavantages of ORM frameworks like hibernate

Comment: I know the paradign mismatch and thats why I am using Hibernate,but whats the need of @OneToOne if it could be handled with normal HQL joins

Comment: so basically the need to @Mapping in Hibernate is that we don not need to have any join statements???

Comment: i would suggest to go through the paradigm mismatch again . Refer to Java Persistence with Hibernate by Gavin king